# Get the sum of fields in table for same id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the sum of Qty,price for same doc_no,Tables are as follow

1)  Registration

```
  id name contact
  123 abc 123456789
```

2) bookingReg

```
   PkBkID FkRegID ac_no
   1       123     QT123
```

3) products

```
   PkPro FkBkID pro_name Qty price doc_no
    1     1     abc      2   150    1
    2     1     def      1   400    2
    3     1     ghi      5   500    3
    4     1     abc      2   150    1



SELECT ac_no, SUM(Qty) Qty, SUM(Price) Price,doc_no from Register,bookingReg,products where bookingReg.FkRegID=Register.id and
  bookingReg.PkBkID= products.FkBkID and (select distint doc_no from products)
```

Comment: May I suggest you investigate the `GROUP BY` clause of SQL?

Comment: The sum only need `products` table, why do you list three table here?

Comment: For an additional checks, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
SELECT
  b.ac_no,
  SUM(p.Qty) Qty,
  SUM(p.price) Price,
  p.doc_no
FROM Registration r
INNER JOIN bookingReg b
  ON b.FkRegID=r.id
INNER JOIN products p
  ON p.FkBkID=b.PkBkID
GROUP BY p.doc_no;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70ed5/2

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any other table, but only the products table and use the below simple query

> select doc_no,sum(Qty), sum(price) from products group by doc_no
>   having  doc_no=1;